# Gitlab-CI : triggering a stage based on the Status of the previous stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHuBu.png)

Hello - I'm using Gitlab 10.x Enterprise version.

This is in the context of a Production deployment to an environment having eight servers. The requirement is to deploy to one server first, and then after couple of days do a deployment to the remaining servers with the press of just one button.

Pipeline Stages:
  Release-Tag-Creation -> Production-OneServer-Deployment -> OneButtonPush -> DeploytoAllServers

Question:

How can I tie the dependency between the stages "*OneButtonPush*" and "*DeploytoAllServers*"?. "*DeploytoAllServers*" stage should be kicked-off  only when the Status of the job in the  "*OneButtonPush*" stage is successful. "*DeploytoAllServers*" stage will have parallel jobs to deploy to each server.

I made few attempts based on the Gitlab CI documentation, but wasn't successful. Also, can the concept of Rolling deployment used in the context of GitLab-CI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gitlab CI, the [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) are run one after another. Each stage can have multiple [jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#jobs) which run in parallel.

As per your use case, you'll need to have different stages each for Release-Tag-Creation, Production-OneServer-Deployment, OneButtonPush and DeploytoAllServers. You can have manual triggers for particular jobs (OneButtonPush in your case) by specifying `when: manual` in the job definition.

By default, if there is a job awaiting manual trigger, jobs from further stages will start executing considering the job with manual trigger as successful. To change this behavior one will need to use `allow_failure: false`. Mode details on allow_failure over [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when-manual)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the **Stage** only after then `specific` one get **successful** you can use the **needs**

Example

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - deploy_dev_lambda
  - test_dev_lambda

deploy_dev_lambda:
  stage: deploy_dev_lambda
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - ./deployLambda
  environment: dev
  variables:
    TARGET_ENV: "dev"
    TAG_NAME: main-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

test_dev_lambda:
  stage: test_dev_lambda
  needs:
    - deploy_dev_lambda
  script:
    - ./testLambda
```

So `test_dev_lambda` only run after the `deploy_dev_lambda` stage and if stage `deploy_dev_lambda` fails  `test_dev_lambda` wont get executed.

Comment: I get an error in Gitlab pipelines: Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: jobs:codeception_tests_staging config contains unknown keys: needs

Comment: not used the keys anywhere in config, could you please post the new question with details i think that would be helpful, and others also will be able to helpout. make sure stages you have defined exist with proper name.

Comment: My problem was an older Gitlab version (11 IIRC)